# Laravel multi domain app structure

Tags: laravel, structure

I need advice.

I have CRM on laravel. We are doing booking now. There will be one common database. How to organize correctly?

1. One application with different namespaces and domain routes.
2. Two application

How do they design such systems?

Thanks!

Comment: It all comes down to your needs. It's the same users table? you'll manage the access to your applications with roles? what's more annoying for you to maintain? are you working alone? will you want to access functions from one app in the other? do you share resources between apps? will the models become so big that they are no longer easy to maintain? ... etc.

Comment: There will be different users, but some services will overlap. So I think all the same there will be one application with different of namespaces

Answer (score 0):

If you’re sharing a database, I would say one application with namespaces and routes.

Possibly put your ‘admin’ in an Admin namespace, to separate it entirely from the rest of the application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I also think so too

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar app. Since  they'll all be using the same database, It makes your life considerably easier to use the same project for all domains.

Split your domains into name spaces. Generally, I prefer to namespace my routes, controllers, and API Resources.

I also use Services to handle the business logic and maintain consistency across domains.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to organize your application in multiple independent services accessible only through REST APIs.

This is how usually enterprises handle their business logic, since they do not have many applications with database access, but rather a more controlled way of handling calls using APIs.